# emacs make-network-process fails, how to debug?

Tags: php, debugging, emacs, geben

I've been using geben on emacs just fine.

after I rebooted, I can't run geben.

I debugged the elisp and found `make-network-process` produces error, but I can't debug it because its native.

The error output is
`(file-error "make server process failed" "Success" :name "DBGp listener<10003>" :server 1 :service 10003 :family ipv4 :nowait t :noquery t :filter dbgp-comint-setup :sentinel dbg\
p-listener-sentinel :log dbgp-listener-log)`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Emacs are you running?  I have 25.1.50.2 and `make-network-process` fails on everything for me.

Comment: @JoeS: yes that was the reason for me as well, I can accept if you turn it into an answer.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the issue.  This seems like a bug with emacs.  I posted it over at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24548/make-network-process-fails-in-emacs-25.  I'd rather wait for a solution.